# Select range starting at A2

Tags: excel, vba

I found the following code to take the data on the TrialBalance worksheet and convert it into a table. It creates the table and renames it, but the range needs to start at A2 where my table heading are stored.

```vb
Sub ConvertTrialBalanceToTable()
Dim wb1 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook 'Trial Balance Template File

wb1.Sheets("TrialBalance").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Select
If ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count < 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add.Name = ActiveSheet.Name
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is `wb1.Sheets("TrialBalance").` the `activesheet`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I think it would have to be where `Activesheet` is used since the previous line was `SELECT` in that sheet. Not a fan of using `SELECT` like this, but it should work in this usecase.

Comment: Sorry i'm not really familiar with vba. I'm learning as I go. I am running the macro from a different sheet in the file, so I need to specify which sheet to create the table on. The TrialBalance sheet is copied into the file each month as is. I have other indirect formulas that reference the column names, but i need it in table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convert '`CurrentRegion`' to Excel Table When Occupied Rows Above or Columns to the Left of First Cell

- If the code is in the *TrialBalance template file*, use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`.

```vb
Sub ConvertTrialBalanceToTable()
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TrialBalance")
        If .ListObjects.Count = 0 Then
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
                RefCurrentRegion(.Range("A2")), , xlYes).Name = .Name
        End If
    End With

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a reference to the range starting with the first cell
'               of a range and ending with the last cell of the first cell's
'               Current Region.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCurrentRegion( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefCurrentRegion"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With FirstCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = FirstCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - FirstCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - FirstCell.Column)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```